# How To split String A,B,C,D,"E,F",G,H

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split this String  `A,B,C,D,"E,F",G,H` with `comma(,)` operator but not split the `"E,F"`.. I want this following output.

```
A
B
C
D
E,F
G
H
```

Comment: post the code to spot the issue

Comment: share your code related to that case.

Comment: Use some CSV parser.

Comment: You could first split for `"` and second for `,`.

Comment: please share what you have tried. Stackoverflow does not believe in questions that sound like 'give me d codez'. for more information on how to ask at stackoverflow, see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023095/use-regex-to-split-with-char-avoid-between-two-char

Answer (score 0):

this may help:

```
    String s = "A,B,C,D,\"E,F\",G,H";
    String[] tmp = s.split(",\"|\",");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            result.addAll(Arrays.asList(tmp[i].split(",")));
        }else {
            result.add(tmp[i]);
        }
    }
```

The `result` list contains the elements

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex will match any string ending with a comma outside `"`: `"([^\",]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\",]*(,|$)"`, so you can split the string on comma or end string character matching the regex, like in this function:

```
private static List<String> splitByComma(String s) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\",]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\",]*(,|$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find() && matcher.start() < s.length()) {
        output.add(s.substring(matcher.start(), (matcher.end() == s.length())?matcher.end():matcher.end() - 1));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that does not use regexps:

```
private static List<String> splitQuoted(String string) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    int idx = 0;
    int start = 0;
    boolean inQuote = false;
    while (idx < string.length()) {
        char ch = string.charAt(idx++);
        if (ch == '"') {
            inQuote = !inQuote;
        } else {
            if (ch == ',' && !inQuote) {
                res.add(string.substring(start, idx - 1));
                start = idx;
            }
        }
    }
    if (start != idx)
        res.add(string.substring(start));
    return res;
}
```

It should scale well as the input string grows, since it only ever looks forward.  You could improve upon its efficiency further by using `char[]` arrays instead of `String.charAt()`, too.  It also leaves the quote characters in the output values, but it would be fairly trivial to remove them as you go.

Answer (score 0):

regex to achieve expected results:

```
String stringToSearch = "A,B,C,D,\"E,F\",G,H";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(?:[^\",]+|\"[^\"]+\")+");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(stringToSearch);
while (m.find())
{   
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can fix it by using replace();

```
String replaceString=s1.replace("\"","");//replaces all occurrences of "\"" to ""
```

Then split .

Comment: He doesn't want to split "E,F".