# Use regex to split with char avoid between two char

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Consider i have a String like this :

```
String str = "a,b,c,d," + char1 + "e,f" + char2 + ",g,h,i,j";
```

How to split every thing with `,` avoid every thing between `char1` and `char2` that not `,`.

I can use this regex `,(?![^()]*\\))` to split only if `char1 = '('` and `char2 = ')'` like this :

```
char char1 = '(', char2 = ')';
String str = "a,b,c,d," + char1 + "e,f,g" + char2 + ",h";
String s2[] = str.toString().split(",(?![^()]*\\))");
```

I get this result :

```
a
b
c
d
e,f,g
h
```

So how to generalize this to use any char in `char1` and `char2`.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "any char"? Can char1 and/or char2 be a ',' (comma) ?

Comment: This question looks familiar... look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021220/how-to-split-string-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h)

Comment: @Betlista nope sorry can't be a `,` i forgot this part i will edit my question

Comment: Is it possible to split the strings before they are concatenated? And if not, are you able to control what char1 and char2 are before concatenation? That way you could enter a wildcard in both so you could focus the regex on that wildcard.

Comment: Use `"(?:" +Pattern.quote(char1) + ".*?" + Pattern.quote(char2) + "|[^,])+"` to *match* the tokens.

Comment: yes @QBrute it is similar i want to generalize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *matching* approach: match any substring between the chars you define and then any character not equal to a `,` and the user-defined chars.

```
char char1 = '|', char2 = ')';
String str = "a,b,c,d," + char1 + "e,f,g" + char2 + ",h";
String ch1_quoted = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(char1));
String ch2_quoted = Pattern.quote(Character.toString(char2));
List<String> s2 = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ch1_quoted + "(.*?)" 
                                    + ch2_quoted + "|[^," + ch1_quoted + ch2_quoted + "]+", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        s2.add(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    } else {
        s2.add(matcher.group(0)); 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

See the [Java  demo](http://ideone.com/yWoUsa).

The `Pattern.DOTALL` is used to make `.` match line break characters - just in case.

See the [sample code regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oORW7/2).

Comment: Sorry, can you improve your pattern to remove the two characters in result so instead to `|e,f,g)` the result should be without this two chars like so `e,f,g`

Comment: i think it is my mistake in question i put `a
b
c
d
(e,f,g)
h` instead to `b
c
d
e,f,g
h`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/yWoUsa. Not sure it will work as expected as I do not know what your data looks like.

Comment: ooohh this is it it work perfectly you are good thank you you can edit your answer i already changes my question